# Moto G phone continuously shows dialogs saying "Unfortunately, SomeApp has stopped"

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, fastboot, motorola-moto-g

My Motorola G phone continuously shows crash dialogs of the app. Multiple dialogs appear on top of each other and if I press ok, the dialog reappears immediately. Due to these dialogs, I cannot use the phone. I am not even able to turn on developer options as the dialogs are not letting me do anything.

I tried to format the phone by pressing power and volume down option. But when I press recovery or factory option, the phone reboots with the above issues.

I also tried fastboot commands to erase data but I didn't get success in formatting the phone.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: have you done any installations/updations?

Comment: @RahulGopi haven't done any updations/installations

Comment: which app is continuously closing?

Comment: @RahulGopi All the apps

Answer (score 0):

Flashing the phone should solve the issue if it is not hardware related(damaged eMMC). The issue may occur when phone is infected by malwares.

This [guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2542219) on XDA Developers may help you out.